# Create new column based on values in 300 adjacent rows of another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column y in my dataframe that is True if the next 300 rows of the corresponding row in column x of my dataframe are all 0, and False otherwise (so then I can just delete all rows that have y = True). My reasoning for doing this is that I just want to delete all rows of my dataframe that have 300 0's in a row in column x.

I have around 150,000 rows in my dataset, so iterating through all the rows is too slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

I've tried iterating through all the rows, which is too slow. I've also tried something like

```
for i in range(len(final_agg_df.index)):
    final_agg_df["to_delete"][i] = (final_agg_df["EDA"].iloc([[i, i+300]]) == 0).all()

final_agg_df = final_agg_df[final_agg_df["to_delete"]==False]
```

which doesn't seem to work (I get error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'), and I'm also not sure if this is the fastest way. Thanks!

Edit:
My sample data would have a timestamp as the index, with many columns, of which one is "EDA", the column that determines whether or not I want to delete my data at a row. 

`index               EDA
4/8/2019 9:20        3
4/8/2019 9:21        2
4/8/2019 9:22        0

4/8/2019 9:23        1
4/8/2019 9:24        0
4/8/2019 9:25        0
4/8/2019 9:26        0
...                  ...`

Here, there are 3 rows in a row with EDA = 0 starting at 4/8/2019 9:24. If there were 300 rows in a row, I would want to delete the entire row with index 4/8/2019 9:24. To do that, I would first want a new column that is "True" if my row should be deleted, so something like this:

`index               EDA     to_delete
4/8/2019 9:20        3       False
4/8/2019 9:21        2       False
4/8/2019 9:22        0       False

4/8/2019 9:23        1       False
4/8/2019 9:24        0       True
4/8/2019 9:25        0       False
4/8/2019 9:26        0       False
...                  ...`

Hope this clarifies!

Comment: can you show some sample data with your expected output? I think you could achieve this with a simple boolean mask, but need to see your data to be sure.

Comment: Sure! just edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a 100% sure I understand your question, but how about"

```
(df['EDA'] == 0).rolling(300).sum().shift(-299) == 300
```

Basically what you are doing is constructing a series that is 1 if value is zero, 0 if otherwise.

You are then calculating a rolling sum with a window of 300, and shifting it back 299 spots. This results in a value of 300 if and only iff that value and the next 299 (so 300 in total) are all zero.

To see a simple example, lets consider a simpler case where you want to delete if there are 3 zeroes in a row

Lets consider

```
 ser = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Then if we do

```
 ser1 = ser == 0
```

We get

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
```

Doing

```
 ser2 = ser1.rolling(3).sum()
```

We get

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
```

Finally doing

```
ser2.shift(-2) == 3
```

We get

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

I believe this should give us the correct answer, as we want a True value if and only if there are three 0s in a row, and the only True value here is for index 1 which is correct